# N grams for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I am doing sentiment analysis on reviews of products from various retailers. I was wondering if there was an API that used n grams for sentiment analysis to classify a review as a positive or negative. I have a CSV file filled with reviews which I would like to run it in python and hence would like an API or a package rather than a tool.
Any direction towards this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try a NN approach for sentiment analysis? Example: https://github.com/SqrtPapere/SentimentAnalysis_CNN

Comment: @Luca Angioloni My dataset isn't big enough. I only have 30k reviews. As far as I'm aware, Neural network requires a much bigger dataset.

Comment: Not necessarily, in the example I provided the NN is trained with 25k reviews.

Comment: But you need a training dataset. If this guy has 30k reviews and he has no labels, there's no training data available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use textblob package.  It offers a simple API to access its methods and perform basic NLP tasks.  NLP is natural language processing. Which process your text by  tokenization, noun extract, lemmatization, words inflection, NGRAMS etc. There also some other packages like spacy, nltk.  But textblob will be better for beginners.